# Close current tab using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript

I tried to close current tab in my ajax success using following command

```
window.close();
```

but that function didn't work, I tried some solutions given in here(stackoverflow) that too doesnt work. It throws the following browser console warning.

> Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.

Is there any way to close it. kindly suggest any way to close it through javascript/jquery

Comment: The warning is very clear: A script can only close windows or tabs that it opened. A script can't close the window that's in, since that was opened by the user, not by the script.

Comment: Is there any other way to perform closing tab in ajax success. Because its my single page application .

Comment: No, Javascript is simply not allowed to close the user's tab.

Comment: Just replace the contents with a `You are now logged out` page.